# Java comm API doesn't show any ports

Tags: java, eclipse

I have use javax.comm library but it didn't worked as i am on x64 system so i tried rxtx. I've put the `rxtxSerial` and `rxtxParallel` dll files in                     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin and the RXTXcomm jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\ext and also into Eclipse's builde path. This is my code, which show absolutely no message as he probably doesn't find any ports. Some help would be much appreciated as i am confrunting this issue for some time. I don't know if this has anything to do with but in Device Manage i do not have any Ports heading or anything related to. I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;    
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
public class JavaPOS {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers ();
          while (port_list.hasMoreElements ()) {                 // Get the list of ports
                  CommPortIdentifier port_id =
                          (CommPortIdentifier) port_list.nextElement ();

                  // Find each ports type and name
                  if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                  {
                      System.out.println ("Serial port: " + port_id.getName ());
                  }
                  else if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
                  {
                      System.out.println ("Parallel port: " + port_id.getName ());
                  } else
                      System.out.println ("Other port: " + port_id.getName ());

                  // Attempt to open it
                  try {
                      CommPort port = port_id.open ("PortListOpen",20);
                      System.out.println ("  Opened successfully");
                      port.close ();
                  }
                  catch  (PortInUseException pe)
                  {
                      System.out.println ("  Open failed");
                      String owner_name = port_id.getCurrentOwner ();
                      if (owner_name == null)
                          System.out.println ("  Port Owned by unidentified app");
                      else
                          // The owner name not returned correctly unless it is
                          // a Java program.
                          System.out.println ("  " + owner_name);
                  }
             }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by installing this : http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm